# Twilio Voice call issue in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

i'm working on twilio Voip call. I have followed the documentation of twilio and according to docs i have downloaded there project and followed there instruction and change the base url according to mine which in php. Now i'm geting the token. I'm passing that token to the delegates method but call fails to connect. I have enabled the audio call from the capabilities also. But still it isn't working. This is my code for twilio voice call,

```
func callFetchVoiceTokenAPI() {

    let param = [
        "token" : LoginToken!,
        "identity" : myPhoneNumber!
    ] as [String : Any]

    ServerCall.makeCallWitoutFile(fetchVoiceTokenUrl, params: param, type: Method.POST, currentView: self.view) { (response) in

        print(response ?? JSON.null)

        if let json = response {
            if !json.isEmpty {

                let token = json["token"].stringValue
                print(token)
                let success = json["success"].boolValue
                print(success)
                self.placeCall()
               UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "voiceToken")
               UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            }
        }
    }
}
func placeCall(){

    if (self.call != nil && self.call?.state == .connected) {
        self.call?.disconnect()
       // self.toggleUIState(isEnabled: false, showCallControl: false)
    } else {
        let uuid = UUID()
        let handle = "Hello Hamza"
        print(uuid)
        performStartCallAction(uuid: uuid, handle: handle)
    }

}
 // MARK: Call Kit Actions
func performStartCallAction(uuid: UUID, handle: String) {
    let callHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: handle)
    let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction(call: uuid, handle: callHandle)
    let transaction = CXTransaction(action: startCallAction)
    print(callHandle,startCallAction,transaction)
    callKitCallController.request(transaction)  { error in
        if let error = error {
            NSLog("StartCallAction transaction request failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        NSLog("StartCallAction transaction request successful")

        let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
        callUpdate.remoteHandle = callHandle
        callUpdate.supportsDTMF = true
        callUpdate.supportsHolding = true
        callUpdate.supportsGrouping = false
        callUpdate.supportsUngrouping = false
        callUpdate.hasVideo = false

        self.callKitProvider.reportCall(with: uuid, updated: callUpdate)
    }
}
func performVoiceCall(uuid: UUID, client: String?, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void) {
    let accessToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "voiceToken")
    if accessToken != nil  {
        print(accessToken!)
    }else {
        completionHandler(false)
        return
    }

    call = TwilioVoice.call(accessToken!, params: [twimlParamTo : twimlParamTo], uuid:uuid, delegate: self)
    print(call!)
    self.callKitCompletionCallback = completionHandler
}
```

This is what comes when all the code perform,
[image]

Comment: When you say "it's not working" what do you mean exactly? The screenshot seems to indicate a call was started, but that looks like an incoming call. Do you get an error message, either in the app, in the [Twilio debugger](http://twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger) or on the phone call?

Comment: Only this screen is shown and nothing is shown before.

Comment: Is it working in simulator ?